# How do I overlay spatial data and return s4 class data

Tags: r, overlay, spatial-data-frame

I'm trying to run this code from a work book

```
meuse.ov <- overlay(meuse.grid, meuse)
meuse.ov@data <- cbind(meuse.ov@data, meuse[c("zinc", "lime")]@data)
```

"meuse" is a `SpatialDataFrame`

"meuse.grid" is a `SpatialGridDataFrame`

The function `overlay` is deprecated so I am using `over` instead, however the resulting "meuse.ov" file is not S4 class data. I assume "meuse.ov" needs to be a `SpatialDataFrame` in order to proceed with the second line of code.
Can anyone suggest a way I can convert "meuse.ov" into a `SpatialDataFrame` or suggest an alternative to `over` that will produce one?

Comment: Are you using `over` the right way? Shouldn't it be `over(meuse, meuse.grid)`?

Comment: We can't see what's going on unless we know how you created meuse in the first place? Could you point us to the source text or at least give us summary(meuse)? SpatialDataFrame isnt really a thing, it should be something like SpatialPolygonsDataFrame or SpatialPointsDataframe...

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack exchange. Yes @Pascal my code was meuse.ov<-over(meuse, meuse.grid). the code and data is from http://spatial-analyst.net/book//  data is "meuse.zip" and code is "meuse.R". "Meuse" is a SpatialPointsDataFrame but I'm not actually sure what the "meuse.ov" output is supposed to be, only that it seems to need to be S4 class. Cheers